# ListBuilder not filtering with createInExpression

Tags: sulu

I have asked already on Slack, but maybe someone will answer here.

I wanted to filter list in adminUI so I can get only items I need, and I used **createInExpression**. Code I set is:

```
if($request->query->get('team') !== null)
{
    $team = $this->teamsRepository->findById($request->query->get('team'), $request->getLocale());
    if($team)
    {
        $teamPlayers = $team->getTeamPlayers();
        $listBuilder->createInExpression($fieldDescriptors['id'], $teamPlayers);
    }
}
```

When I debug, I get:

```
$teamPlayers = [ 1 ] << I wanted this, it is correct
```

And, when I see what doctrine SQL-s do, I get that DOCTRINE builds query like:

```
…WHERE p1_.id IN (?), and parameters is [ 1,2,3 ] << this is wrong
```

Can someone, please, help why this is happening, and how can I achieve needed filter...

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found problem.

Haven't look that good. **$listBuilder->createInExpression()** only creates it, not applying it, I just needed to call:

```
$listBuilder->in($fieldDescriptors['id'], $teamPlayers);
```

And now it works OK...

Sorry for taking time..